# Meteor: Images and text do not load after moving to Iron:Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

My site works fine when the data is in a template, but once I try to route to it using iron:router, a background image and most remaining content no longer appear. (Some of the content still appears with working css, JS components so I know that those files are being read. Also, when inspecting the element, all the text, images are still visible in the code, but not the website.

This works fine (index.html):

```
<body>
  {{>home}}
</body>
```

This adds another {{>home}} section, but the new section is having issues rendering as explained above (router.js):

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the latest `iron:router`? I had a similar problem, and inquired about it in this pull request: 
https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1051
Latest response indicates this should be fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

You've followed the wrong tutorial :( There are plenty of tutorials and articles out there explaining to define routes like you did.

However, the Iron Router [project page](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) explains how to define routes differently. 
For more information on routes, have a look at [this article about Iron Router](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/7cce3ca0-2e7b-4603-90c5-570b646f0dd7/entry/meteor_part_4_router?lang=en) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: problem was not with iron:router but rather that not all elements were loaded into the page yet. Document.ready() works fine when I directly called template.

Issue is that when iron:router loads the template, the new page elements are being loaded after the JS files were already called (JS that animates the images/text in).

Solution: use rendered instead of document ready:
    Template.MyTemplate.rendered = function(){
    }